collcell and \IfBlankTF comparison not working
I'm having trouble with the \collcell package - a macro I made, which uses \IfBlankTF, works fine outside of a table, but somehow \collectcell is feeding something that's "non-blank" into my macro, and it's very confusing. I'd be very grateful if anyone had any suggestions as to how to make this work. The below MWE illustrates the issue.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{collcell}

\begin{document}

\newcommand\myMacro[1]{%
    ``#1'' is \IfBlankTF{#1}{blank}{not blank}%
}

myMacro uses the LaTeX IfBlankTF test\newline

Testing myMacro with a space inside: \myMacro{ }\newline

Testing myMacro with a character inside: \myMacro{space}\newline

Passing table entries in to myMacro with collcell:\newline
\begin{tabular}{%
    c | >{\collectcell\myMacro}c<{\endcollectcell}
}

    Result of non-blank cell & non-blank \\\hline
    
    Result of blank cell & \\

\end{tabular}

\end{document}


A change in array hasn't been reflected in collcell, so an internal token causes confusion. Try
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{collcell}
\makeatletter
\def\collect@cell@arg#1{%
  \cc@case
    \\{\collect@cell@cr#1}%
    \end{\collect@cell@checkend}%
    \csname{\collect@cell@checkcsname}%
    \textonly@unskip{%
      \let\collect@cell@spaces\empty
      %\collect@cell@addarg{#1}% do not include the \unskip
      \collect@cell@look%
    }%
    \unskip{%
      \let\collect@cell@spaces\empty
      %\collect@cell@addarg{#1}% do not include the \unskip
      \collect@cell@look%
    }%
    \@sharp{%
      \expandafter\collect@cell@addarg\expandafter{#1}%
      \collect@cell@look
    }%
    \collectcell{%
      \advance\collect@cell@count by \@ne
      \collect@cell@addcc%
    }%
    \endcollectcell{%
      \ifnum\collect@cell@count=\z@
        \expandafter\collect@cell@end
      \else
        \expandafter\endgroup
        \expandafter\collect@cell@addarg\expandafter
        {\expandafter{\the\collect@cell@toks}}%
        \advance\collect@cell@count by \m@ne%
        \expandafter\collect@cell@look
      \fi
    }%
    \cci{%
      \collect@cell@look
    }%
    \default{%
      \expandafter\ccell@swap\expandafter
        {\csname endtabular*\endcsname\endtabular\endarray}{\in@{#1}}%
      \ifin@
          \expandafter\@firstoftwo
      \else
          \expandafter\@secondoftwo
      \fi
      {\collect@cell@cr\\#1}%
      {%
        \collect@cell@addarg{#1}%
        \collect@cell@look
      }%
    }%
 \endcc@case
}
\def\collect@cell@cr{%
  \iffalse{\fi
  \let\collcell@realcr\cr
  \def\cr{%
    \collect@cell@look
    \collcell@realcr
  }%
  \iffalse}\fi
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\newcommand\myMacro[1]{%
  \showtokens{#1}%
    ``#1'' is \IfBlankTF{#1}{blank}{not blank}%
}

myMacro uses the LaTeX IfBlankTF test\newline

Testing myMacro with a space inside: \myMacro{ }\newline

Testing myMacro with a character inside: \myMacro{space}\newline

Passing table entries in to myMacro with collcell:\newline
\begin{tabular}{%
    c | >{\collectcell\myMacro}c<{\endcollectcell}
}

    Result of non-blank cell & non-blank \\\hline
    
    Result of blank cell & \\

\end{tabular}

\end{document}

